# How to insert a given timestamp with sqlx

Tags: go, sqlx

This question is specific to [`github.com/jmoiron/sqlx`](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/).
I want to insert a known timestamp or date with Named Queries. How do I do that? I use `time.Now()` as an example of a given timestamp.

Here is my table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
   id int(11) NOT NULL,
   name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   ts timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

```
package main

import (
    _ "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "log"
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

type book struct {
    Id int
    Name string
    Ts time.Time
}

func main() {
    db, err := sqlx.Open("mysql", "xxx:xxxxx@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname?parseTime=true&charset=utf8")

    if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

    v := book{Id: 1, Name: "Book", Ts: time.Now() }

    fmt.Println(v)
    stmt, err := db.PrepareNamed(`INSERT INTO book VALUES (:id, :name, :ts)`)
    _, err = stmt.Exec(v)
}
```

Here is the error I have:

```
{1 Book 2019-08-06 09:21:15.178503955 +0000 UTC m=+0.000601133}
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x28 pc=0x604ec6]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/jmoiron/sqlx.(*NamedStmt).Exec(0x0, 0x65c980, 0xc00010a060, 0xc00010a060, 0x0, 0x6cfaa0, 0xc000112020)
/root/go/src/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/named.go:43 +0x26
main.main()
/root/go/src/dbtest/sqlx_insert.go:37 +0x284
exit status 2
```

Comment: Looks correct to me. Only thing to do that I can think of is actually go into the SQLX code and see why it's mentioning a nil pointer dereference.

Comment: maybe `stmt` is `nil`, `err` not checked

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! The timestamp column name actually was changed by an automation script. False alarm! everything works perfectly. Thanks everyone!